# NodeJS Sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

Hy and thanks in advance, So im working on a project, where part of the requirements, is to have a field where the user can insert is e-email, and then receive a custom url on his e-mail account, from there he can access the site. This is like the example of a "password-reset", where a custom url is generated and sent to u with a time-stamp validation. Im very new to nodejs, and my question here is if anyone has some type of guidlines to start doing this. My idea was to generate a sessionID, then generate a custom url, send the email, and then the users goes to the webpage. Im using express, and the whole site is already assembled, its just this feature tha is killing me! :(

Comment: Use hashing to generate a unique hash value for the email, and then append it with the url. You should also add the timestamp to the hashing calculation.

Comment: Very helpfull, thank you. But i need a couple more things, like the ability to log the user actions on the website, what pages he visited and what actions he commited, for that i need sessions, that saves the user history in cookies, or am i thinking it all wrong here? Thanks for your answer, i really apreciated it

Comment: @pakkolol a simple captcha and hashing with some time limitation to reset the password (as mention above), will do the trick to actually know that its the owner who is resetting the password and not some other guy, although this way might not work if the user email is compromised. Send an email with updates that the password was reset,  just in case. Also take a look at two-factor authentication where a PIN is send to email or cellphone which is valid for a limited time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need, but here is what I'd suggest (spoke about this on Reddit earlier).

```
// If you want the user to **have** to be a custom URL
req.param('userId', function(req, res, next) {
    db.getUser(userId, function(e, usr) {
        if (e) throw new Error(e);

        req.user = usr;
    });
});

req.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) return res.redirect('/login');
});

// Rest of routes
req.get()
req.post()
```

That being said, you normally shouldn't have user login this way.  Normally you would set the user in the session and validate it that way.  [Here's a good article on setting up sessions in Express.](http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/express-js-sessions-a-detailed-tutorial/)

If you do it this way, you would do something like this:

```
req.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
    var userId = req.session('userid');
    if (!userId) res.redirect('/login');

    db.getUser(userId, function(e, usr) {
        if (e) throw new Error(e);
        if (!usr) return res.redirect('/login');

        // Now the user is accessbile through its session
        req.session.user = usr;
    });
});

// Rest of routes
req.get()
req.post()
```

Password resetting requires what's called a nonce.  This will be a small object in your DB that has a created date.  You email them a link to your site that uses that nonce.

Whenever the route is hit that uses the password reset nonce, you look it up in the DB, verify it's new enough (within X hours or days), then give them access to the route that resets their password.

Your project requirements are pretty vague, so I'm not exactly sure what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding you want how to implement password reset functionality using expressjs.

Here are steps
  1. 
for forgot password
   create an API

```
   app.post('/forgotpassword',function(req,res){
     var email = req.body.email;
      // validation
      // your custom url creation logic here
      // someurl/:resetpasswordtoken
      // store this in user data
      // for this I'll suggest to use any unique string creation logic*

   }
```

2. to show reset password page

   ```
    app.get('/someurl/:resetpasswordtoken, function(req,res) {
      //check token exist
      // render the page for reset like current passwor,new password
    }
   ```
3. Action for reset password

   ```
    app.post('/someurl/:resetpasswordtoken , function(req,res){
       var currentPwd = //get current pwd
       var newPwd = //get new pwd
       //check token 
       //then reset password  for user
    }
   ```